# Unity3D: Only a Cube appears while trying to spectate through Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors, mr-spectatorview

I am using Azure Spatial anchors as my Spatial Alignment Strategy.

Please let me know if I did anything wrong

So, if user side Hololens views a hologram, I want the same hologram to be viewed by the Spectator as well.

I have a main scene where I have a hologram and it works normally how I want in my user side Hololens.

Now I added a `SpectatorView` prefab to this scene, set the role to `User`, and added the user side IP address of the Hololens.

After following these steps https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView#basic-unity-setup ( Keys are added properly, Updated all asset caches)

I open the `SpectatorView.HoloLens` scene, and now I have the SpectatorView prefab there as well, but the Role is set to `Spectator` and added the IP address of the user side again.

While building for user side Hololens, I generated a build with only main scene present

and for spectator side Hololens, I generated a build with only `SpectatorView.HoloLens` scene.

Hologram appears in the user side Hololens. But nothing appears in the Spectator side Hololens.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: wasn't there two options; either broadcasting the whole scene or only specific objects, by attaching a broadcast-Script to them?

Comment: @Perazim I did broadcast the whole scene and the cube is present in the SpectatorView.HoloLens scene, not in the main scene

Comment: It's difficult for us to find the cause of the problem from your post, and asking the details of the project bit by bit is inefficient and cumbersome. For convenience, please provide a minimal reproducible sample (avoid privacy information) so that we can locate the problem or  find a solution.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863758/unity3d-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-obj-microsoft-mixedreality-spat