# Unity3D: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: obj : Microsoft.MixedReality.SpatialAlignment.SpatialAnchorsCoordinateService.RequestSessionStart ()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I am trying to use Spectator View in Unity3D and Hololens. So, I am using another Hololens as the Spectator.

I followed these steps  https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView#basic-unity-setup, but it didn't work with my HoloLens (Not able to spectate anything, nothing shows up) . So, I am opened two Unity instances of same application to test and debug the problem. I opened the main scene in one instance and the spectator scene in another instance and I set user ip as `127.0.0.1`

So these are logs I'm getting in User side instance

[image]

```
[11/14/2019 18:39:25][Unity][CRITICAL] Unity Exception ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

    Parameter name: obj : Microsoft.MixedReality.SpatialAlignment.SpatialAnchorsCoordinateService.RequestSessionStart () (at Assets/MixedReality-SpectatorView/SpatialAlignment.ASA/Scripts/SpatialAlignment/SpatialAnchorsCoordinateService.cs:67)
    Microsoft.MixedReality.SpatialAlignment.SpatialAnchorsCoordinateService+<TryCreateCoordinateAsync>d__18.MoveNext () (at Assets/MixedReality-SpectatorView/SpatialAlignment.ASA/Scripts/SpatialAlignment/SpatialAnchorsCoordinateService.cs:235)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I am not sure what this issue is. Is it because I'm using Unity editor? or this the reason its not appearing in Hololens as well. How can I fix this? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I think because you opened it in two instances the spatial anchors can't be shared. This would make sense with the message `Value cannot be null` because it requests spatial anchors but doesn't get any.

Comment: From the exception you shared, I noticed the keyword: SpatialAlignment.ASA. It's related to Azure Spatial Anchor(ASA), have you checked if ASA is setup correctly?